# How to count value from strstr function php?

Tags: php, arrays, string, strstr

I try to get value after symbol '@' and count it. But this code doesn't give the correct result. How to fix it?

```
$t="Hi, I invite @nina and @nana to come to my party tomorow";
$arr=explode(' ', $t);
foreach($arr as $user ) {
$result=strstr($user, '@');
$total = $count($result);
}
echo $total;
```

> Result = 1
>
> Expected Result =2

Comment: Look carefull at `@arr=explode(' ', $t);`.

Comment: Also there is more wrong with your code. Please include working code (and check whether that is really the case) to your question.

Comment: Every time the code loops (from `foreach`) you are assigning the count (incorrect here as `$count()` when it should be `count()`). Each time the code loops, it will assign a new value to `$total`. If you want a cumulative total, instead of `$total = count($result);`, use `$total += count($result);` At the start of the loop, before the foreach statement, initialize the value with `$total = 0;`

Comment: You named it `$total`, you want to store a total in it, however you put a new value in it on each iteration. And the value you put in it is wrong, btw.

Comment: Use the return from  `preg_match_all()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/23268269/2943403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you explode it with @?

```
$t = "Hi, I invite @nina and @nana to come to my party tomorow";
$arr = explode('@', $t);
$total = count($arr) - 1;
echo $total;
```

**EDIT**: As suggested by @mickmackusa, if you want to avoid counting solitary @, you can count those on the side and then subtract.

```
$t = "Hi, I invite @nina and @nana to come to my party tomorow";
$arr = explode('@', $t);
$solos = explode('@ ', $t);
$total = count($arr) - 1 - count($solos);
echo $total;
```

Comment: Because that won't identify solitary `@` symbols.  A mention will need to be followed by non-whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$t="Hi, I invite @nina and @nana to come to my party tomorow";
$arr=explode(' ', $t);
$total =0;
foreach($arr as $user ) {
$result=strstr($user, '@');
$total = $count($result);
$total++;
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: This code-only answer was not tested and will not work.  Why is it upvoted? This answer is wasting the time of researchers.